# Robolectric testing on multiple sdk levels?

Tags: android, robolectric

I am using Robolectric to run my Android unit tests on an app that is configured with minSdkVersion 16 and targetSdkVersion 25. Should I run the Robolectric tests with corresponding minSdk and maxSdk values (`@Config(minSdk = 16, maxSdk = 25)`)? Is it totally unnecessary to run the tests on all supported sdk levels or does it make sense? Obviously, the tests run a lot slower when I test on all sdks.

Markus

Comment: We always run against latest possible version. However we don't have much alternate cases in app that depends on the API version.